# On the Review page, can we bring Suggested Edits that already have votes to the top?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review

I think that Suggested Edits could be processed by the community a little faster if edits that already have at least one vote were shown first. That way, edits that are partially reviewed are not pushed to the very bottom of the page, as sometimes happens with the current setup.

Comment: Just because an edit already has a vote doesn't mean you're supposed to not think about your own vote.

Comment: I think I've reworded my question a little better.

Comment: That *is* better wording. +1